# Create two dimensional array from string, but ignore a specific character

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

this is my string, and I want it to convert into 2D Array.

```
mail@mail.com;"Hi ;John";man;405089;

mail@mail.net;Hi Sarah;woman;405089;
```

And I want to create array from this. I fount this code:

```
$ret = array_map (
  function ($_) {return explode (',', $_);},
  explode (';', $data)
);
```

Therefore instead of ',' would be ';' and instead of ';' would be '\n', right?

But It doesn't work correctly yet. If you look once more, there is "Hi **;** John"..

I want make this code to ignore everything inside of " ", because there is a semicolon.

Comment: Firstly try to split string properly. Then thin about building an array.

Comment: And what is your expected output

Comment: That looks like it could be parsed by CSV-handling functions, specifying `;` as the field separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First remove characters between and including ", then run your function. Here is a one line code to remove `"Hi ; John"` from your string:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\".*?\"/', '', $subject);
```

- `\"` matches the character `"` literally
- `.*?` matches any character (except newline), Quantifier: `*?` Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
- `\"` matches the character `"` literally

Answer (score 4):

Instead of explode, take a look at [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

This will handle your case with the semicolon inside the quotes if you specify a delimiter, like so.

```
str_getcsv($_, ';')
```